# Как менять User Agent с Selenium на Python в браузере Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webbrowser

Скажите пожалуйста почему данный код не берёт из файла txt элементы(строки User Agent) по порядку, он берёт первый элемент, а затем больше не меняет User Agent в цикле, а мне нужно чтобы он брал следующий элемент из блокнота и т.д.

```
UA = open('useragents.txt').read().split('\n')
for i in range(3):
    useragent = UA.pop(0)
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path="D:/WebDrivers/geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64/geckodriver.exe")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get("http://atomurl.net/myip/")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Возможно потому что вы забыли проставить отступы после `for`.

Comment: Сам по себе код работает отлично (проверил, составив свой список user-agents). Можете куда-нибудь скинуть пример вашего файла?